# How does wilcox_test understand which column specifies the individual sample in paired test?

Tags: r, pairwise.wilcox.test

How do I know that wilcox_test (package rstatix) recognizes the correct column for each individual sample, when doing a paired test?

Here is an example:

```
install.packages("rstatix")
install.packages("datarium")
library(rstatix)
library(datarium)

data("mice2", package = "datarium")
mice2.long <- mice2 %>% gather(key = "group", value = "weight", before, after)

mice2.long  %>% wilcox_test(weight ~ group, paired = T)
```

It seems the test works correctly, but I didn't specify the column "id" to represent the individual sample designation, and thus how did the test understand that this column identified the "pairs"?

Comment: Where is `statix` defined? I can only find [`rstatix`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstatix/index.html).

Comment: Correct, it should be rstatix. I've amended.

Comment: I understand, typos happen. Please, however, always try the code that you give us. Many questions go down the wrong path of troubleshooting simply because of a typo that had nothing to do with the real code underneath. Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: Oh the argument passed to paired is TRUE. the function will correlate the first value of before to the first value of after and so on . It does not need the column id. But if the data is not arranged such as the first value of before directly correlated to the first value of after, the function `wilcox_text` would give incorrect results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument passed to paired is TRUE. the function will correlate the first value of before to the first value of after and so on . It does not need the column id. But if the data is not arranged such as the first value of before directly correlated to the first value of after, the function `wilcox_text` would give incorrect results.

Here is a quick example:

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:10,matrix(rnorm(20, 15,2),,2))|>
  setNames(c('id', 'before', 'after'))
 
dat %>%
  gather(key = "group", value = "weight", before, after) %>%
  rstatix::wilcox_test(weight~group, paired  = TRUE)
# A tibble: 1 × 7
  .y.    group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic     p
* <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 weight after  before    10    10        14 0.193
```

Now if we randomize the long data, such that the 1st value of before does not correspond with the first value of after, we should get different results

```
set.seed(1)
dat %>%
   gather(key = "group", value = "weight", before, after) %>%
   slice_sample(n = 20)%>%
   rstatix::wilcox_test(weight~group, paired  = TRUE)
# A tibble: 1 × 7
  .y.    group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic     p
* <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 weight after  before    10    10        15 0.232
```

Try again with a different seed and you get different results.

Note that this is not the same for your case, ie randomizing `mice2` does not produce different results. Why? because all the values of `before` are smaller than all the values of `after`. ie the maximum of the values before is smaller than the minimum of the values after:

```
mice2$before|>max()
[1] 235
mice2$after|>min()
[1] 337
```

This is very critical in computing the wilcox statistic in that regardless of the permutation, all the differences of `after - before` will be positive and thus all the ranks will be grouped as positive thereby we just need to `sum(1:10) = 55`. This is the test statistic.

```
mice2 %>% 
  gather(key = "group", value = "weight", before, after)%>%
  rstatix::wilcox_test(weight~group, paired  = TRUE)

# A tibble: 1 × 7
  .y.    group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic       p
1 weight after  before    10    10         55 0.00195
```

Comment: Thank you @Onyambu. Great response and kind of you to give the extra insight! I wish the function did have the possibility to specify an ID-column, simply to guarantee the right results without having to check the order of the data set, but now at least I know how to check that the conditions are met for a correct result.